# SQL Concatenate 2 rows to create unique key

Tags: concatenation, uniqueidentifier

I have a table where each side of an FX transaction is represented in a new row:

[image]

I would like to combine this into a unique key that would be PaymentDate+currency1+currency2+(concatenation of notional), maybe something like:
15/06/2018JPYUSD-1000000095238

is this possible to do within an SQL select statement?

Comment: is `transaction` unique for every transaction? if yes you can use this for your unique identifier.

Comment: it is, but i am joining two tables later on in the code, and the second table doesnt have that field, so i need a unique key present in both tables which i can join on...